# Convert 4bit VGA to 1bit VGA

Tags: fpga, vga, nexys

I have [Nexys A7 FPGA](https://digilent.com/shop/nexys-a7-fpga-trainer-board-recommended-for-ece-curriculum/) and I would like to play this game on it

Here is my: https://github.com/juanmard/screen-pong

Now the first problem I encoutered is that my FPGA requires 4 VGA RED and 4 green and 4 blue pins, while this game only requires one

As you can see here: https://github.com/juanmard/screen-pong/blob/master/stage-01/vga_controller.v

there is only 1 output for each color required
while my FPGA has 4 outputs like constraint file implies

```
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[0] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_AD14N_35 Sch=vga_r[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[1] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_AD6N_35 Sch=vga_r[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[2] }]; #IO_L1N_T0_AD4N_35 Sch=vga_r[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[3] }]; #IO_L8P_T1_AD14P_35 Sch=vga_r[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[0] }]; #IO_L1P_T0_AD4P_35 Sch=vga_g[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[1] }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_AD5N_35 Sch=vga_g[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[2] }]; #IO_L2N_T0_AD12N_35 Sch=vga_g[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[3] }]; #IO_L3P_T0_DQS_AD5P_35 Sch=vga_g[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[0] }]; #IO_L2P_T0_AD12P_35 Sch=vga_b[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[1] }]; #IO_L4N_T0_35 Sch=vga_b[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[2] }]; #IO_L6N_T0_VREF_35 Sch=vga_b[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[3] }]; #IO_L4P_T0_35 Sch=vga_b[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_HS }]; #IO_L4P_T0_15 Sch=vga_hs
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_VS }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_AD1N_15 Sch=vga_vs
```

Now what do do, do I just take one red output and call it a day, or do I have to somehow split 1 output that the games vga_controller requires into 4?

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the 1-bit output to any two colors you want, defined by the RGB values. Although it might be easiest to use black and white, which in your case will be all RGB bits 0 for black and all RGB bits 1 for white. But it seems you have 8 color output, one bit per color, so you could use the bit as MSB only for slightly darker colour, or copy the bit to all bits, for bright colour. Or you can mix whatever colours you want, you have 3 input bits so you can use a colour lookup table to tweak every colour to your liking.